# Should a Chunker find the head of a phrase?

Tags: nlp, opennlp

My application requires that I point the head of a phrase (noum or verb). I have this kind of info in my Portuguese corpus:

Me pron-pers *B-NP 
pergunto v-fin B-VP 
sempre adv *B-ADVP 
quem pron-indp *B-NP 
podia v-fin B-VP 
ter v-inf I-VP 
sido v-pcp I-VP 
aquele pron-det B-NP 
jovem adj I-NP 
alemão n *I-NP 
. . O

The syntax is similar to CONLL 2000, but the * marks the head of the phrase.
My question is: should a Chunker support head? Do you know any other corpus to train a Chunker that also includes head, or it is a particularity of mine?

-- edit --

I tried training the classifier and got good results: F1 score was 0.94 without head mark and 0.93 with it. I think it is OK. The problem is that the OpenNLP chunker API does not support this mark and gets confused while creating the spans. I changed the OpenNLP code to handle it and I was wondering if it is a good patch, but since it is not common I should not send the patch.

Comment: Head = main = _núcleo_ (in Portuguese). A parser can find the head of a phrase, but a chunker can do it much faster. Example in English: if _a beautiful sunset_, the head is _sunset_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen a chunker that supports head-finding, so I can't help you with a corpus. What you might do, if you already have a chunker, is formulate a bunch of rules that designate the head after the chunker has found it, or train a classifier to do so. You can train it on your corpus and apply it on chunker output.

Comment: Thanks @larsmans. I tried training the classifier and got good results: F1 score was 0.94 without head mark and 0.93 with it. I think it is OK. The problem is that the OpenNLP chunker API does not support this mark and gets confused while creating the spans. I changed the OpenNLP code to handle it and I was wondering if it is a good patch, but since it is not common I should not send the patch.